# Downloaded an Amazon S3 file doesn't contain data

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, vue.js, download

I'm writing a service to download a file in an Amazon S3 bucket, but I'm receiving nothing but an empty JSON object

Vue | Axios -

```
downloadLocations() {
  axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/targetLocation/downloadSearchData")
      .then((response) => {
        const  content = new Blob([JSON.stringify(response.data)],{ type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' })
        const fileName = `test.txt`
        saveAs(content, fileName)
      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
```

Java | Springboot Service -

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream downloadSearchData() throws IOException {
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .withRegion(awsRegion)
            .build();

    S3Object s3Object = s3client.getObject("downloadable-cases", "7863784198_2021-08-16T13_30_06.690Z.json");
    InputStream is = s3Object.getObjectContent();
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int len;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    while ((len = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    return outputStream;
}
```

THIS works, accept it downloads it to the project, and not my machine (which is the whole point) -

```
public void downloadSearchData() throws IOException {
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);
    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
            .withRegion(awsRegion)
            .build();

    S3Object s3object = s3client.getObject(
            "downloadable-cases", "7863784198_2021-08-16T13_30_06.690Z.json"
    );
    S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent();
    FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, new File("hello.txt"));
}
```

Comment: Note that you will usually have better performance and reliability by instead constructing a signed URL to the S3 object and redirecting the client there instead of proxying it. (I also recommend using jets3t instead of the lousy AWS client.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few comments here:

1 - you are using the older V1 Amazon S3 Java API. You should consider moving to V2 as Amazon recommends using over V1.

***The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.***

See the [Amazon SDK for Java V2 Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html)

2  - when using Amazon Java V2 APIs, you do not need to hard code your creds in the code. To work with V2 and creds, see: [Using credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html).

As you are using Spring BOOT app, here is an example that uses Amazon S3 Java V2 API and Spring BOOT. This app lets you download an object located in an S3 bucket to your browser.

[image]

The downloaded Object is valid and i can open it and view it (its not empty or corrupt):

[image]

Amazon S3 Java V2 code to get an object from a bucket is:

```
// Get the byte[] from this AWS S3 object.
public byte[] getObjectBytes (String bucketName, String keyName) {

    s3 = getClient();

    try {
        GetObjectRequest objectRequest = GetObjectRequest
                .builder()
                .key(keyName)
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();
        
        ResponseBytes<GetObjectResponse> objectBytes = s3.getObjectAsBytes(objectRequest);
        byte[] data = objectBytes.asByteArray();
        return data;

    } catch (S3Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

See this developer article that shows how to work with Amazon S3 Java V2 API and other services within a Spring Boot app:

[Creating an example AWS photo analyzer application using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)

This link guides you through creating this Spring app....

[image]

Comment: I'll definitely do it this way. Dumb question, I'm assuming .key(keyName) is the file name inside the bucket, yes?

Comment: Correct - in my image example - key is lake.png as shown in the screen shot

Comment: Also - for the latest Amazon S3 Java V2 code examples - refer to this Github code repo here:  https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3

Comment: Awesome. I'll save that link! Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have followed [the official AWS example "Download an Object"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#download-object) so your code looks correct. You forgot to close the input stream by calling `is.close()` at the end, however it's unlikely that this is the problem.

You can simplify your code by using `try-with-resource` block and [`InputStream.transferTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo(java.io.OutputStream)) method:

```
var s3Object = s3client.getObject("downloadable-cases", "7863784198_2021-08-16T13_30_06.690Z.json");
var out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try (var in = s3Object.getObjectContent()) {
  in.transferTo(out);
}
return out;
```

Perhaps the S3 file has no content, if you download it using AWS Console will it show any content? If it works from AWS Console you should use a debugger to see what happens in your code.

Comment: Strange. I downloaded it directly from the console, and it certainly does. When I use your method I get an empty JSON object